# Joomla 3.8 site not able to clear cache

Tags: caching, joomla

I have a strange behaviour in my Joomla 3.8 site.
For example I created a new menu item; after I saw it in my site, I moved it in the menu order; but even if I moved it, if I refresh the site, it is always shown in the original position. Even if I purge cache and expired cache, nothing is changing.

Any idea?

Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: What theme are you using?  Each theme can define how it builds the menu, it may not be using the menu ordering data at all.

Comment: the menu item position is a single sample, but I have also the issue that if I change the content of hte joomla article linked to the menu item, it does not show the changes. So I think it is a cache issue

Comment: There may be other caching enabled apart from the Joomla cache such as SiteGround "Dynamic Cache" or LiteSpeed Cache or similar.